# Having issues getting page title from html with meteor.http package

Tags: javascript, http, meteor

```
Meteor.http.call( 'GET', 'http://google.com', {}, function( error, response ) {
      if ( error ) {
    console.log( error );
  } else {
    console.log( response );
  }
});
```

the problem is it keeps showing this error this is my first time using this package so am not sure if i really understand it.

this is the error on my console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://google.com. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: This is a security feature of the browser. Do a google for Access-Control-Allow-Origin and read about it.  There is a way to fix it here http://enable-cors.org/server_meteor.html

Comment: @MikeKing don't tell people to do a google search for something they've been googling for days, I find that quite irritating. I would still like to thank you for the link although it was useless to me but thank anyways.

Comment: If you are using chrome, you can try this extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: My apologies @emmanuel-amodo There is another way to do it with Meteor- I'll put it in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP Requests from the browser will always run into this CORS issue unless you specifically allow them with CORS headers.

Meteor has a good way of dealing with it. First up you do a call:

```
Meteor.call("httpRequest","http://myserver.com/path/to/file",params);
```

In the server you write a Meteor method like this

```
Meteor.methods({
    httpRequest: function(url,params) {
    // Send the http request here
    })
});
```

You cannot do a call back to the client with the result of the http request, but you can put it into a database record, which the client subscribes to.

Comment: @MikeKing Thanks a lot, sorry for my reaction earlier, I have a list if urls that users submitted, I want to be able to get the title page and other meta data automatically pls can you walk me through that, here is what I have done. [what I have done so far](https://forums.meteor.com/t/having-issues-getting-page-title-with-meteor-http-package/29907/4?u=emmanuelamodu)